# How to get the latitude and longitude to Oncreate method

Tags: java, android

**i am storing address details to firestore. now im using mapview in this activity. and its getting current location. now i want to pass the longitude and latitude to firebase , then i need to get the values to oncreate method.**

i am using Address_location variable , i want to get latitude pass to that

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_address);

    mName = findViewById(R.id.ad_name);
    mCity = findViewById(R.id.ad_city);
    mAddress = findViewById(R.id.ad_address);
    mCode = findViewById(R.id.ad_code);
    mNumber = findViewById(R.id.ad_phone);
    mAddAddressbtn = findViewById(R.id.ad_add_address);

    mStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //TESt
    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    fetchLastLocation();


    mAddAddressbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = mName.getText().toString();
            String city = mCity.getText().toString();
            String address = mAddress.getText().toString();
            String code = mCode.getText().toString();
            String number = mNumber.getText().toString();
            String final_address = "";
            if (!name.isEmpty()) {
                final_address += name + ", ";
            }
            if (!city.isEmpty()) {
                final_address += city + ", ";
            }
            if (!address.isEmpty()) {
                final_address += address + ", ";
            }
            if (!code.isEmpty()) {
                final_address += code + ", ";
            }
            if (!number.isEmpty()) {
                final_address += number + ", ";
            }

            Map<String, String> mMap = new HashMap<>();
            mMap.put("address", final_address);
            mMap.put("name", name);
            mMap.put("Address_Lane", address);
            mMap.put("city", city);
            mMap.put("Postal_code", code);
            mMap.put("Phone_number", number);


            mStore.collection("User").document(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                    .collection("Address").add(mMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(AddAddressActivity.this, "Address Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                    }

                }
            });


           


        }
    });


**i want the latitude value and longitude here**
    Toast.makeText(AddAddressActivity.this,Address_location, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

private void fetchLastLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]
               {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_CODE);
        return;
    }
    Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            if (location != null){
                currentLocation = location;
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), currentLocation.getLatitude()
                //       +""+currentLocation.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                String Address_location = Double.toString(currentLocation.getLatitude());


                SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
                        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(AddAddressActivity.this);
            }
        }
    });

}



@Override
public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(),currentLocation.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
            .title("I am Here.");
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,5));
    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                fetchLastLocation();

            }
            break;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your use case properly, you should be using member variable for  lat & long, until its null don't update details just yet. if you want to update anyway even if onsuccess method is not yet called, start a thread that waits until that variable is not null and then call update to firebase method.

Comment: public void address_passer(String address_location) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), address_location, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }